# How to make the bottom part of 2 divs align

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Im currently trying to make the bottom of two divs, a title and a navbar, to line up vertically, but I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how to make that work. vertical-align:bottom in the CSS doesn't seem to work. To clarify, I want the "GOT/IT" text and the nav bar text elements to line up vertically (bottom). The code is shown here:

```css
.navbar-default {
  padding-top: 65px;
  padding-left: 45px;
  padding-right: 45px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #2e9eed;
}
.header-text {
  font-size: 64px;
  color: blue;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 20%;
}
.header-item-text {
  background-color: green;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">

      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span class = "header-text">GOT/IT</span></a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->


      <!-- Desktop + Tablet View -->
      <div class="hidden-xs">
        <div class="pull-right collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="header-item-text"><a href="#">THE WHY</a>
            </li>
            <li class="header-item-text"><a href="#">THE WHAT</a>
            </li>
            <li class="header-item-text"><a href="#">VALIDATE</a>
            </li>
            <li class="header-item-text"><a href="#">ABOUT</a>
            </li>
            <li class="header-item-text"><a href="#">CONTACT</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please specify the problem in your code - what doesn't work exactly?Than its easier for us to help you.

Comment: That's probably not going to be easy. There is space around text characters by design...that's what you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are trying to vertically align the bottom of two columns. You can try using a table for this like the following:

```
<table >
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align:bottom">
            <div>
                ....
                ....
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align:bottom">
            <div>
                ....
                ....
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give equal padding-left to both div.
I would suggest use bootstrap CSS.
You can also use HTML table tags.